# Mysql update statement with join involved

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 `mysql` tables called **tbl_flats** and **tbl_blocks**.

I'm joining these two tables like this:

```
select 
    `f`.`fld_id` AS `fld_flat_id`,
    `b`.`fld_block_name`,
    `f`.`fld_mobile_app_password`,
    `f`.`fld_site_id`
from
    `tbl_blocks` `b`
        left join
    `tbl_flats` `f` ON (`f`.`fld_block_id` = `b`.`fld_id`)
where
    `f`.`fld_site_id` = 57
```

It displays like this:
[image]

Now what I'm trying to do is update `fld_mobile_app_password` columns to **NULL**. Here's what I've tried but failed:

```
    update (select 
            `f`.`fld_id` AS `fld_flat_id`,
            `b`.`fld_block_name`,
            `f`.`fld_mobile_app_password`,
            `f`.`fld_site_id`
    from
        `tbl_blocks` `b`
            left join
        `tbl_flats` `f` ON (`f`.`fld_block_id` = `b`.`fld_id`) )
set 
    `f`.`fld_mobile_app_password` = '1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72'
where
    `f`.`fld_site_id` = 57
```

I can't seem to figure out the problem. Any tip is appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't update columns in a subquery in MySQL.  Just remove the subquery:

```
update `tbl_blocks` `b` join
       `tbl_flats` `f`
        on `f`.`fld_block_id` = `b`.`fld_id`
   set  `f`.`fld_mobile_app_password` = '1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72'
   where `f`.`fld_site_id` = 57;
```

An inner join should be sufficient here -- the `where` clause turns the outer join into an inner join anyway.

Comment: Ah I understand now. Appriciated